# MooTools and jQuery integration

Tags: jquery, continuous-integration, mootools

I am using the code [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) (1.11) and jQuery (1.2.6). It's working fine when these are
separate. While I am integrating Firefox, it throws:

> (document).ready(){} is not a function.

Is anything wrong in my concept? What do I do to rectify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(function($){ 

   $works with jQuery here. 
});
$ Works with MooTools here.
```

However, that said, I would suggest you ditch the MooTools.

Its complete modification of all object prototypes can cause cause jQuery's functions to randomly and unexplainable cause errors, and on top of that, MooTools' modification of all object prototypes (the Object and Function prototypes are even modified), have, in my experience, resulted in jQuery performing significantly slower than without, simply for MooTools being on the same page.

Additionally, MooTools is 50 KB and jQuery is 25 KB (average numbers, including extensions). Having them both will drastically slow down page load just for the extra data fetch.

A project I was working was having problems with JavaScript performance, and I'm talking *really* *serious* slowdowns, in seemingly simple code. We migrated to jQuery, and there was no performance gain *until* we stopped loading the MooTools when we'd finished migrating the code, and then as soon as we dropped MooTools, the speed came back.

Comment: Minified and GZipped, MooTools is *not* anywhere close to 50k. It's closer to the low 20's. If you do the same to jQuery, it's 18k.

Comment: Plus you also have the option of including or not including large sections of code which will bring the size down even further depending on what you need.

Comment: +1 to ditching mootools, but really just ditch either one. You are forcing users to download to scripts that repeat a lot of functionality between them. If it's for a particular effect from an example it's almost garaunteed someone's done it with the other js library.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery and MooTools both use '$' as a shorthand way of calling their main functions. The jQuery team have built in a way to stop this, so you can write something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

This will let you use jQuery and any other JavaScript library side by side. Read their docuentation on the subject - 
*[Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)*.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to sanchothefat said, you really should try to avoid using two such frameworks together because they essentially do the same thing. If you're not gzipping your Javascript, you're probably sending the user at least 150-200k of JavaScript with just the libraries, nevermind the plugins you're using. Almost anything you do in MooTools can be done in jQuery and vice versa. If you look around, you can probably find scripts that do what you're looking for that have been ported both ways.

Comment: Hi, in general you are right. But the purpose of MooTools is different from the purpose of jQuery, I believe. jQuery simplifies working on DOM, attaches features to DOM elements etc. and MooTools just completely changes the way the JavaScript code is being written. I personally prefer MooTools to write complicated code (it makes the code clean and very maintainable), but jQuery has strong advantages (many available plugins and simplicity to accomplish simple things). Finding a way to use them both in some effective way would be fantastic. But I believe it is not that easy at the moment.

Comment: +1 for pointing out most of the features are doubled and that it is not worth the price

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the use of [.noConlict](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) method of jQuery.
I don't know if it'll be usefull in your case...

Answer (score 0):

MooTools for jQuery: http://moo4q.com/

**jQuery <3 the DOM** jQuery is awesome but it's scope is (generally) DOM [manipulation]
**MooTools <3 Objects** MooTools make working with [javascript] objects huckleberry pie.