# mootools fx.Accordian content not showing for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I'm new to MooTools and I'm trying to implement the fx.Accordian plugin.

I've included MooTools as well as the Accordian plugin. I'm really not trying to do anything much different than what is shown in the demo from the MooTools web site.

In my css, I've inserted:

```
#accordion  {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#accordion H2 {
    background: #99ccff;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10pt; 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 3px 5px 1px;
  }

#accordion .accordion_content {
    background-color: #F4F5F5;
}

#accordion .accordion_content p {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0 6px 8px 6px;
}
```

Inside a script tag in my header file I have:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
   new Fx.Accordion($('accordion'), '#accordion h2', '#accordion .accordion_content');
});
```

And then I'm trying to do something like the following in HTML:

```
<div id='accordion' class='customized'>
<h2>What not #1</h2>
<div class='accordion_content'>
    <p>What not #1 is being displayed now</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I get the accordion H2 displaying properly, however, when I click on it the accordion content doesn't display. Can anyone help me to see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, all you need to do is add more accordion sections to your html. From the documentation:

"The Fx.Accordion class creates a group of Elements that are toggled when their handles are clicked. **When one Element toggles into view, the others toggle out.**"

So an accordion with a single element does not make much sense - being the only one, it will always be the active element no matter what you do.

I added one more `<h2>` toggler and another content `<div>` to your original code and it works perfectly. See http://jsfiddle.net/YayQD/1/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was testing it on one, on the assumption that when I got it to work, I'd add the rest.

Comment: However, it still doesn't work. After some tinkering around on jsfiddle.net (awesome site BTW) i found that it appears my use of MooTools is somehow being messed up by the fact that I'm using a jQuery $(document).ready elsewhere in the same file. Any ideas? (I'm seeing if I can find anything right now)

Comment: Apparently jQuery.noConflict(); is supposed to accomplish this? No luck yet, though.

Comment: Yes, having two libraries on the same page is never a good idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491066/mootools-and-jquery-integration